# Assigning a setTimeout function to a Vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have currently assigned a setTimeout function to a Vue method and I want to use clearTimeout for this function. Is that possible? If so, how can I do this?

```
    methods: {
        timeoutController() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.controllerShown = false;
          }, 3000);
        }
....
```

Comment: You should follow your consideration of using a method instead.

Comment: @AEB yes, you can store the id of the timeout in Vue data property & clearTimeout with that id in an another fn as answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    timer: null
  },
  
  methods: {
    startTimer () {
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("execute me")
      }, 3000)
    },
    // If you kill the timer before setTimeout callback has been executed the callback wont get executed
    killTimer () {
      if (this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="startTimer()">start</button>
  <button @click="killTimer()">kill</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to assign a function to a Vue component's data?

`setTimeout()` will execute the function 3000 ms later and give the timer to `this.timeout`. The timer will never execute again, no matter where you assign to.

Comment: there are scenarios where it's required to clear the setTimeout before it has done executing the callback function, eg. we often clear timeouts in debounce